# FPGA Memory using Verilog Code

Tags: verilog, fpga, system-verilog

Sir,

I designed memory in verilog code which is 76 bit wide and 10 bit long.(76 Columns and 10 Rows). i want to dump this code into spartan 3 FPGA board. so,Where this memory will be placed in FPGA? General purpose Registers or Block ROM Memory of FPGA?. is it necessary to enable Block memory of FPGA by code for such big memory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spartan 3 Block Rams are 18kb each. If your address is 10 bits, you need 1024x76b memory block, i.e. 76kb, which clearly warrants the use of Bram.

Comment: hey Sir,    My memory is 10x76 bits. can i dump it on Spartan 3 ?   and thanks for answer.

Comment: If your memory is only 10 words deep, you might want to consider also the use of [distributed ram](https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/application_notes/xapp464.pdf). For a ROM, the Core generator is an easy way forward.